# How to add dynamic header for out going request ASP.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers, httpmodule

I am having ASP.net application (Application-1) . It will have some API (Application-2) calls. I want to add some Id in header from Application-1 and want to access in Application-2.

I using httpmodule. I am not able find any event to inject header. ( i tried to add in BeginRequest and EndRequest's request header and response header. But, no luck)

Internal call will happen using httpclient. Please guide me. Thanks Advance.

Comment: Please add your code snippet other than would be tough to  resolve for community member

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I am not able segregate this code snippet alone. My ask is very simple. I want to add few header for all outbound request using httpmodule